# How to plot Histogram summary for delta weight in Federated Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am analyzing a method that I have implemented in Tensorflow Federated with FedAvg. I need to have a histogram for every clients' delta weights that are communicated to the server. Each client separately called in `simulation/federated_avaraging.py`, but the thing is I can not call the following API in there. `tf.summary.histogram()`. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TFF, TensorFlow represents "local computation"; so if you need a way to inspect something *across* clients, you will need to first aggregate the values you want via TFF, or inspect the returned values in native python.

If you want to use TF ops, I would recommend using the `tff.federated_collect` intrinsic, to "gather" all the values you want on the server, then `federated_map` a TF function which takes these values and produces your desired visualization.

If you would rather work at the Python level, there is an easy option here (this is the approach I would take): simply *return* the results of training at the clients from your `tff.federated_computation`; when you invoke this computation, this will materialize a Python list of these results, and you can visualize it however you want. This would be roughly along the lines of something like:

```
@tff.federated_computation(...)
def train_one_round(...):
  ...
  trained_clients = run_training(...)
  new_model = update_global_model(trained_clients,...)
  return new_model, trained_clients
```

In this example, this function will return a tuple, the second element of which is a Python list representing the results of training at all clients.

Comment: Thank you keith, I've been implementing scenario 3 and got this error. TypeError: Cannot pack sequence into type <class 'list'>, only structures of AnonymousTuple are supported (received a structure with types [AnonymousTuple([('conv2d/kernel', <tf.Tensor: id=10439, shape=(3, 3, 1, 32), dtype=float32, numpy=[a lot of weights]. I think AnonymousTuple can not be passed as a list as mentioned. What should I do to pass it?

Comment: Hi amir, would you mind opening a separate issue for this with a stacktrace? It's hard to diagnose without a little more context. Thanks!